# jQuery fadeToggle not removing display:none

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

CSS:

```
.hidden-content { display:none; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="exp-col-content-holder">
   <img class="club" alt="Pen Pal Club"     src="http:/site.com/wp-content/themes/familycenter/images/club-penpal.jpg" />
     <a class="expand-content-link club-link" href="#">Pen Pal Club</a>

    <div class="hidden-content">Our Pen Pal Club provides kids with an opportunity to meet other Laurel Springs students around the world, and maybe in their own home towns. It is a time to relax, share information, trade stories, and make new friends.</div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(".expand-content-link").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("ecf_opened").parent(".exp-col-content-holder").find(".hidden-content").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Issue:
I am trying to use slideToggle to fade In some hidden content when the link is clicked. Everything seems to run as intended, but the "display:none" property on the hidden-content class never gets removed and therefore the hidden content is never revealed. I can see the opacity and height being animated, but display:none never is removed from the element.

But if I double click the link...the hidden content flashes for a split second and disappears again.

Seems like everything should be running properly to me.

What could be causing this? There are no JS errors in console or anything.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/v3qLm/ ... it must be other element

Comment: works here too http://jsfiddle.net/eSC5L/

Comment: Does seem to have the issue you mentioned here http://jsfiddle.net/BLpA4/

Comment: It has to be an issue with my theme then. I've gone through and deactivated all plugins but the issue persists. I'll have a run through of the theme. Thanks for taking a look you guys.

Comment: If you can post the url ... and we can check the problem

Comment: Unfortunately It's something I am developing on a localhost or I definitely would have included from the get go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine for me, if your still facing the issue,instead of css try hiding the content in jquery using `.hide()`, when the page loads initially. See the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hidden-content").hide();
$(".expand-content-link").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("ecf_opened").parent(".exp-col-content-holder").find(".hidden-content").slideToggle();
    return false;
}); 
});
```